# Python time localtime to gmtime conversion issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I am trying to convert a Unix epoch time from local (eastern time, UTC -4) to UTC and produce a new Unix timestamp in UTC. When I convert the local timestamp to a time struct, and then convert it to UTC the conversion happens fine. But, when I generate a Unix time stamp from the generated time struct that gives a time that is one hour ahead of the correct UTC value. What could be going wrong here?

```
local_tstamp = 1533957121
print(time.localtime(local_tstamp))

time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=23, tm_min=12, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=222, tm_isdst=1)

gmt_time = time.gmtime(local_tstamp)
print(gmt_time)

time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=3, tm_min=12, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=223, tm_isdst=0)

gmt_tstmp = int(time.mktime(gmt_time))

print(time.localtime(gmt_tstmp))

time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=4, tm_min=12, tm_sec=1, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=223, tm_isdst=1)
```

Comment: I don't understand the 1st sentence. A Unix epoch timestamp is [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) "the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.mktime(t)` takes a  *local* time, not GMT.  Since the value you passed in had dt=0, but local time actually is in `dst`, you get a value one hour ahead:

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html?highlight=localtime#time.localtime):

> time.mktime(t)
>
> This is the inverse function of localtime(). Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the time in **local** time, not UTC.